# JSON data reading error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'd like to grab the latitude and longitude values for this entire set of JSON data:

```
          {
            branches =             (
                                {
                    city = "Las Vegas";
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "3.35";
                    distanceInMiles = "2.08";
                    id = 15739653;
                    latitude = "36.029102";
                    longitude = "-115.114960";
                    name = "Las Vegas - 89123";
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "8876 Eastern Avenue";
                    telephone = "";
                }
            );
            id = 355896;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net";
            name = "Body Heat";
        },
                {
            branches =             (
                                {
                    city = "Las Vegas";
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "18.09";
                    distanceInMiles = "11.24";
                    id = 6043133;
                    latitude = "36.143978";
                    longitude = "-115.280380";
                    name = "Las Vegas - 8645 W Sahara Ave.";
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "8645 W Sahara Ave.";
                    telephone = "";
                }
            );
            id = 121022;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net/31513.jpg";
            name = "Just Face It Medspa";
        },
                {
            branches =             (
                                {
                    city = Henderson;
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "3.66";
                    distanceInMiles = "2.27";
                    id = 4563174;
                    latitude = "35.997353";
                    longitude = "-115.120628";
                    name = Henderson;
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "3035 W Horizon Ridge Pkwy., Suite 100";
                    telephone = "";
                }
            );
            id = 57146;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net/31513.jpg";
            name = "Signature Institute of Aesthetic Sculpting";
        },
                {
            branches =             (
                                {
                    city = "Las Vegas";
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "9.71";
                    distanceInMiles = "6.03";
                    id = 13769564;
                    latitude = "36.106091";
                    longitude = "-115.166840";
                    name = "Las Vegas - 89109";
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "145 East Harmon Avenue";
                    telephone = "";
                }
            );
            id = 272131;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net";
            name = "Luxury Suites International";
        },
                {
            branches =             (
                                {
                    city = "Las Vegas";
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "25.24";
                    distanceInMiles = "15.68";
                    id = 10385118;
                    latitude = "36.238758";
                    longitude = "-115.224167";
                    name = Northwest;
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "5803 W Craig Rd., Suite 104";
                    telephone = "";
                },
                                {
                    city = "Las Vegas";
                    country = "United States";
                    countryIsoCode = USA;
                    distanceInKms = "5.65";
                    distanceInMiles = "3.51";
                    id = 9391473;
                    latitude = "36.067402";
                    longitude = "-115.172226";
                    name = "Posare Salon Town Square";
                    state = Nevada;
                    stateIsoCode = NV;
                    street = "6569 S Las Vegas Blvd.";
                    telephone = "";
                }
            );
            id = 216657;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net";
            name = "Posare Salons";
        }
    );
    owners =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net/media/1830.gif";
            name = OneBigPlanet;
            type = group;
        }
    );
```

How would I do that? I've tried doing using the following, but it keeps returning errors saying that

GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: -[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9f9e90
2013-09-09 14:24:46.851  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9f9e90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f7d012 0x2780e7e 0x30084bd 0x2f6cbbc 0x2f6c94e 0x118646 0x125952 0x126e59 0x2a0053f 0x2a12014 0x2a027d5 0x2f23af5 0x2f22f44 0x2f22e1b 0x2ed77e3 0x2ed7668 0x16c4ffc 0x51d1d 0x3285)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

I'm just trying to grab all the longitude and latitude to store it as a doubleValue and then plot the points onto a map. Any ideas?

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://api.onebigplanet.com/ws/local-daily-deals?wsToken=&wsVersion=3.0.0&categoryId=1&categoryId=2&numItems=0&out=json&sort=distance&zipCode=89123&radiusInMiles=100&latitude&longitude"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                             NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
                                             self.mapLocations = JSON;
                                             for(NSDictionary *locations in self.mapLocations) {
                                                 //NSLog(@"%@",locations[@"merchants"][0][@"branches"][0][@"latitude"]);
                                                 NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", locations);
                                             }

                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                                     NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                             NSLog(@"NSError: %@",error.localizedDescription);
                                         }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: That isn't anything even close to JSON.

Comment: It's a JSON response. According to the API that I used I selected that the output be in JSON. Not only that, but I used NSSerialization so it wouldn't have worked otherwise...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suspect that OP does indeed get some JSON but then it's parsed and this is the description (`NSLog()` output) of the already parsed Cocoa collection object.

Comment: @user2755126 Nevertheless, the data you have pasted here is definitely **not** JSON.

Comment: I guess the format threw me off a bit, but it definitely resembled a JSON response midway through it.

Comment: If you are having trouble with a piece of code, post the code so we can help you solve the problem. From the error it is obvious that you are getting a string where you thought you were getting an array.

Comment: I just added the code. So none of this is being stored as an array?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't just download the contents of the url and then parse it with NSJSONSerialization? That is, if the url does supply JSON and not something else.

Comment: Yes, it's a part of a NSLog of what was probably originally JSON.  He doesn't show us the beginning, though, so we have no idea where he is in "parsing" the resulting structure.  Nor does he.

Comment: OP:  You need to indicate where you got the error.  And show us the relevant part of your JSON dump.  Eg, there is no obvious occurrence of "merchants" in the above structure.

Comment: (And I'd suggest that you not copy code you don't understand.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - As you well know, what he pasted above is part (alas, not a useful part) of the NSLog output from a "nest" of NSArrays and NSDictionaries, most likely the result of parsing a JSON request.  AFJSONRequestOperation is a 3rd-party API which parses a JSON transfer request on the fly and returns the resulting objects.  Apparently the OP's problem is simply another case of not being able to find one's way through a JSON "nest" (something that baffles me, since it's such a simple concept).

Comment: OP: If you search Stack Overflow you will find MANY threads similar to this where people receive a JSON response and do not understand how to "navigate" it. It's really a simple concept, so please, rather than looking for a "quick fix", actually try to understand what's going on.  Start by studying the JSON spec at json.org -- it takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then understand that when you NSLog the parsed result of JSON, arrays are in `()` vs the `[]` in the JSON spec, and the `:` separating a JSON key and value in an "object" is replaced by `=` when the same pair is mapped to an NSDictionary.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback Hot Licks. I think that I need to learn a little bit more what I'm dealing with. It's exactly what you said. i figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: That particular error occurs when using object subscripting in iOS < 5 or in non-Apple LLVM compilers (like GCC).

Answer (score 0):

Use NSJSONSerialization:

```
//getting JSON data from request
NSError *errorJSON = nil
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorJSON];
if(!errorJSON){
    //JSON parsing success
}
```

Object will be Array or Dictionary